# Not sure about my Database Schema

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key, database-schema

I'm new to DB schema design and was hoping I could get some advice.

I am trying to write a small tool for managing access lists for cisco based network devices. I'm stuck on how to model the access-lists and their entries. Here is some information;

An access-list has the following attributes

- A Name and 1 or more access-list entries(ACE)
- An access list entry (ACE) has the following;

  - A Source Network
  - A Destination Network
  - A source Port
  - A Destination Port
  - A Protocol
  - An Action -

Both the Source and Destination Network can be
    -

- An Object-group that references either other object-groups OR a
  NETWORK directly.
- A NETWORK.being a combination of an IP Address and Network Mask

Both the Source and Destination Port can be

- An Object-group that references either other object-groups OR a PORT directly
- A PORT - being an Integer

Object-group's can reference other object groups or a NETWORK  being a combination of an IP Address and Network Mask directly.

There are some more complexities however I wanted to limit my question to what is highlighted above. I have attached a diagram showing how I think I can represent the Source Network as an example.

Any advice is very much appreciated.

[image]